# buttons only react to clicks/touches when clicking/touching to the right of them

Tags: unity-game-engine, click, touch, 2d, mouse

I'm making a 2D game in Unity3D for android. Right now I'm making buttons. And this buttons does not react clicks/touched properly. I've got same issue with mouse clicks and touches both. Every button has trigger boxcollider with a same size as an object. BUT buttons react only when I click on area, that is right from a button. I don't understand why is it so. What should I do? Here is my code:

```
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

        Vector3 i = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 1));
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (i, i);

        if (hit.transform != null) {

            if (hit.transform.tag == "button") {

                hit.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            }

        }
    }
```

Also, I've instantiated an object on mouse click on "i" position to check does it convert screen position to world correctly, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first parameter in `Physics2D.Raycast` is the origin and the second one is `direction` so you should make the raycast from your `ray.origin` in the direction of `ray.direction`

```
 void Update () {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);
            if (hit) {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag=="button"){
                   //do something
              }
           }
        }  
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle it by this way:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y);
    Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos);

    if (hit) {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);

        if (hit.transform.tag == "button") {
            hit.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```